# incorrext syntax when using select statement in ado.net

Tags: sql, ado.net

the sql command i am using

```
Sql command = new sql command(@"If exists" + "(Select * from customer where year = '" + textbox.text +"')"
                       --------next statement ------ ", conn);
```

error i got

> incorrect syntax near Select\r\n incorrect syntax near

Comment: First, rather than looking at the code that constructs the query, print out *the complete string* that is generated and look for errors there (they tend to be more obvious). Second, stop constructing SQL using string concatenation anyway - use parameters to keep SQL code and data separate.

Answer (score 0):

```
using(SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)){

  cnx.Open();
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from customer where year ='"+this.textbox1.Text+"',cnx);
  SqlDataReader myRead = cmd.ExexuteReader();
  // if ure DataRead is Read it's mean that he found it 
  if(myRead.Read()){

    // do something
  }else{ 
    // ure Errors message 
  }

}
```